# What is this part called and where can I buy it?

Tags: windows

So I replaced the weather stripping on all of my *very* old windows yesterday. The windows are sash windows. In the process I unfortunately broke two of the spring-loaded things that hold the top part of the window securely into the frame's guides. Here are some photos of both one I didn't break, and the individual disassembled parts:

[image: Part I Didn't Break]

[image: Disassembled]

So, my questions are:

1. What is this called?
2. Where can I get replacements?

Thank you!

Comment: Tilt window latch maybe . What brand are the windows ?

Comment: @Kris unfortunately I am not sure. They are OLD aluminium windows and frames. Could be as old as 1951.

Comment: https://www.swisco.com/page-id-part?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIo8bD_b254gIVTQOGCh1wFQD7EAAYASABEgLy2PD_BwE.  Try uploading a photo to this company.

Comment: @Kris terrific, done, thanks! Hopefully can self-answer in a few days.

Comment: Those aren’t *very* old windows.  Old windows are made of wood.   *Very* old windows, I don't know, stone or something...

Comment: @Kris swisco solved it for me. Please post an answer so I can award the bounty!

Comment: Kris make sure to elaborate on the link, link only answers are frowned on because the link may be expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a tilt window latch. Use this [hardware replacement company](https://www.swisco.com/page-id-part?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIo8bD_b254gIVTQOGCh1wFQD7EAAYASABEgLy2PD_BwE)
There you can upload a photo of the part you need they may be able to identify it. (I have no affiliation with Swisco.com).

Comment: Thank you, Swisco was able to solve it for me! The part had been discontinued so I had to order a more modern part and retrofit it (drill through the window frame for new screwholes).

Answer (score 1):

Go to  allaboutdoors.com. Guid, or cam sash top, seasonally/white,  May be part in white only.  Only 3 bucks, buy two or more that price. If not part, tons more to look at.   PART#  538009

Comment: The way the parts were going through it seem to be in the later 70s or the eariy 80s time frame .

Comment: I don't understand the punctuation in this

Comment: Look up.  allaboutdoors,com      Has part .

Answer (score 0):

I have Jeld-Wen windows with a similar mechanism. You slide each (one on each side) towards the center of the window, which then allows you to tilt the window into the house for cleaning. I've seen it called the Tilt Latch, but your brand may be different.

As far as the brand- your windows don't look too old. Look in the corners of the glass for an etched brand name and serial number. It can be quite hard to see, so try it with different lighting conditions if at first you don't see it. Mine are in the top left corner of the upper sash.

Comment: Is the house located in New England?  All aluminium ? Does not look to be that old 70 to 80 I give it.Does sash have center sash lock also..Could be a jasco window they did lots of aluminium sliders and windows or a Harvey  window Area may help  to narrow down  brand.

Comment: Could not find anything etched, but tried. You definitely got the "tilt latch" correct!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess Keller Windows Tilt Latch.  This part mounts on top of the window to keep it in its track, but allows you to retract it to pivot the windows.

Looks extremely similar to part 26-088P on swissco.com
https://www.swisco.com/Keller-Pair/pd/Surface-Mounted-Latches-For-Tilt-Windows/26-088P

As others have said, you can upload a photo to them and confirm it.